# React.js Error getting Undefined as response from Server

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, components, data-manipulation

I am fetch some data from my server in node.js to my react.js data is being fetched successful from the function and I see it in my console, but when I want to use it in my component I am seeing undefined. Others fetch functions I am working with work properly;
just that particular function is not working.
The fetch function in my hooks.js file:

```
export async function useFetchMyHomes(){
  const [myhomesData, setMyHomesData] = useState({ isLoadingMyHomesData: true,           myHomesApiData: null, myHomesStatus: null, myHomesServerError: null})

   useEffect(() => {
     const fetchMyHomesData = async () => {
         try {
             const {id} = await getUser();
            console.log('ID from myHouse', id)
             const { data, status } = await      axios.get(`/api/house/getMyhouse/${id}`)
            console.log('Saved House Data', data)
            console.log('status',status)
            if(status === 200){
                setMyHomesData({ isLoadingMyHomesData: false, myHomesApiData: data, myHomesStatus: status, myHomesServerError: null })
            }else{
                setMyHomesData({ isLoadingMyHomesData: false, myHomesApiData:   null, myHomesStatus: status, myHomesServerError: null })
            }
        } catch (error) {
            setMyHomesData({ isLoadingMyHomesData: false, myHomesApiData: null,      myHomesStatus: null, myHomesServerError: error })   
         }
     }
     fetchMyHomesData()
 }, [])

 return myhomesData
}
```

From the code above I receive the data from the backend very well.

The `Myhomes` component where I want to use the information:

```
    function MyHomes({ toggle, isOpen }) {
     const [likedHouses, setLikedHouses] = useState([])
     const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);

    const { isLoading, apiData, serverError } = useFetch()

    const { isLoadingMyHomesData, myHomesApiData, myHomesStatus,    myHomesServerError} = useFetchMyHomes()
    const houseData = myHomesApiData?.data.saveHouseData

    console.log('MY HOUSE DTA', houseData)
```

The `console.log('MY HOUSE DTA', houseData)` gives me undefined as output.

I have checked the code properly but I still can't figure the issue.